# In PsychoPy: Can I change the height of a text component for the second loop?

Tags: python, psychopy

My experiment has two trials within a phase, so that at the end of trial 1 the program loops back to the beginning to begin the second trial.

The last routine at the end of both trials is a routine that contains one attention check question. The attention check questions for each trial are completely different from each other in terms of length (i.e, attention check 1 is short but attention check 2 is long) and response required (attention check one requires a keyboard response, attention check 2 requires a mouse click).

I use the same text component to display each attention checker but I use the following code to specify what question I want at each trial.
if Phase1.thisN==0:
P1attentioncheck=“Based on the text below, what is your favorite soda? \n \nThis is a simple question. You don’t need to be a soda connoisseur in order to answer. When given the options to choose your favorite soda, you need to select carrot juice. \n \na. Coca-Cola \nb. Fanta \nc. Ginger Ale \nd. Root Beer \ne. Mountain Dew \nf. Dr. Pepper \ng. Pepsi \nh. Sprite \ni. Carrot Juice \nj. Other”

elif Phase1.thisN==1:
P1attentioncheck=“Pizza Topping\n \n \nMost modern theories of decision making recognize that decisions do not take place in a vacuum. Individual preferences and knowledge, along with situational variables can greatly impact the decision process. To facilitate our research on decision making we are interested in knowing certain factors about you, the decision maker. Specifically, we are interested in whether you actually take the time to read instructions. If not, then some of our manipulations that rely on changes to the instructions will be ineffective. To show that you have read the instructions, ignore the pizza toppings below, as well as the continue button. Instead, simply click on the title at the top of this screen (i.e., “Pizza Topping”) to proceed to the next screen. \n \nWhich of these toppings would you put on your pizza? \n(Click on all that apply) \n \na. Peppers \nb. Bacon \nc. Chicken \nd. Pineapple \ne. Onions \nf. Mushrooms \ng. Pepperoni \nh. Spinach \ni. Ham \nj. Jalapeños \nk. Sausage \nl. Other”

This is the specific Python Code I am using:

```py
     # Initialize components for Routine "P1_Attention_Check"
P1_Attention_CheckClock = core.Clock()
AttentionQ = visual.TextStim(win=win, name='AttentionQ',
    text='default text',
    font='Arial',
    units='cm', pos=(0, 0), height=1, wrapWidth=35, ori=0, 
    color='white', colorSpace='rgb', opacity=1, 
    languageStyle='LTR',
    depth=-1.0);
P1_attcheck = keyboard.Keyboard()
mouse_2 = event.Mouse(win=win)
x, y = [None, None]
mouse_2.mouseClock = core.Clock()
```

Because the questions differ in length, can I change the letter height of the text component “P1attentioncheck” so that the text is smaller only on the second trial??
Also can I disable the mouse response for the first trial because I only need that component for the second trial? Vice versa for the keyboard responses.

Comment: Try to reformat your question to show code as code. You will get much more help if your question is easily scannable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out I just needed to add a code component to the routine that contained the text/response components for the attention check questions. Within the begin frame section I added the following code:

```
if Phase1.thisN==0:
    AttentionQ.setHeight(1, log=None)
elif Phase1.thisN==1:
    AttentionQ.setHeight(.8, log=None)
```

I also had to make sure the Letter Height within the text component was set to "Set Every Repeat"

Comment: Hi, you can and should accept your own answer - it lets others know you don't need any more assistance. But do be careful about using the "set every repeat" option - if setting attributes in code, this can actually lead to a conflict between your custom code and Builder's graphical settings - it generally shouldn't be necessary with code like yours.